# How to add more than 2 conditions in an If/Else statement in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress

Me again.

So I have been working on this basic search functionality where I am comparing the value entered as text with a list of other values and doing an action based on it.

In simpler words. I am making a search where the logic compares the value with other strings and if the comparison is successful then show  and hide  and vice versa if the condition is false.

Now the other condition i want to implement is that when the text bar(where the user will enter the value) is empty then both the divs should be shown. Below is my code for this:

**HTML where I am getting the value from: - Im using the onchange to get the value - oninput is not working :(**

```
<label>Find your location:</label>

<input type="text" class="form-control" id="search_input" placeholder="Type address..." 
onChange="myFunction()"/>
```

**And This is my JS code**

```
<script>

function myFunction() {
   var inzone = document.getElementById("inzone");
   var outzone = document.getElementById("outzone");
if(document.getElementById("search_input").value == null 
||document.getElementById("search_input").value == "")
{
 outzone.style.display = "";
 inzone.style.display = "";
}
else if (document.getElementById("search_input").value === 'something something')
{
outzone.style.display = "none";
inzone.style.display = "";
}
else {

inzone.style.display = "none";
outzone.style.display = "";

}
```

Comment: You should store the search_input lookup in a variable and reuse that variable.  Other than that, what is not working?

Comment: @Taplar when someone enters a value and its equal to the "something something" a div is hidden as intended and if this condition is false the other div is hidden as intended. Now I want to add another condition the search_input is empty/or someone backspaces and its black then it should show both the divs.

Comment: You're first condition is `value == null || value == ""`.  Related to the answer below, it will never be null, but it should match the "".  And `false || true` should make it go in the first if.  So I'm not sure how this logic is not working.

Comment: If the answer below isn't the solution, please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button); [here's how to do one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/).

Comment: It is working in the first go (when the page loads) - But if i enter something in order to satisfy either of the conditions AND then backspace and empty the input area THAT is the point where the condition doesnt work. Hope you get it.

Comment: @MuhammadQasim - The way SO works, your whole question (including any necessary code) has to be **in** your question, not just linked. Two reasons: People shouldn't have to go off-site to help you; and links rot, making the question and its answers useless to people in the future. Please put a [mcve] **in** the question, ideally using Stack Snippets. More: [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) and [*Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder basically I have 3 conditions I want to check if they are fulfilled and I want this to keep on happening basically the if else would keep on going in a way or something similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`document.getElementById("search_input").value == null` will never be true. The `value` property of an `HTMLInputElement` is **always** a string. It may be `""`, but not `null` or `undefined` (the two things `== null` checks).